How to fix error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ..."?
I'm designing a website. The project structure is
project\
 back_end\
  __init.py__
  main.py

In init.py,
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)    
    return app

In main.py
from back_end import create_app

app = create_app()
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hello world"

When I hit run in VS Code, there is error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'back_end'.
I type python -m back_end.main in the command line, the code works. I also tried to rename the back_end package to b. The error still persists. Is it related to defining an environment variable? I am using Ubuntu 24.04.

One, it is __init__.py  not __init.py__.
Two, your main.py file needs to be in your project/ directory, not project/back_end/. A revised file structure would look like this:
project\
  back_end\
    __init__.py
  main.py

Also, for a simple project like the structure you described, you wouldn’t need to have multiple files like that. A single main.py file would easily suffice.

The init.py is a type. I moved the main.py outside back_end. It worked. The project is under development, I just included relevant files here.

As @DeepThought42 pointed out, the file name should be __init__.py and the project structure should look like this:
project
├── back_end
│   └── __init__.py
└── main.py


Notice the main.py is outside your "back_end" directory.

Also, I don't know why someone will add that code directly inside the __init__.py (should not !). Instead you can use the following approach:
Project Structure:
project
├── back_end
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── app.py
└── main.py

AND __init__.py:
# You can leave this file empty
# Read more about it here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-__init__-py-file-in-python/

app.py:
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

main.py:
from back_end import create_app

app = create_app()
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return "hello world"

app.run()

